# Google Cloud Platform: How can I get a signed URL for putting an object to Google Cloud Store with Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-api-client

I'm using `google-api-python-client` but can't make any progress in how to create signed `PUT URL` just for direct uploading object to Google Cloud Storage Bucket. There is no consistent documentation on how I can get signed URL using the last version of the Google Python client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used the google cloud storage library. I recommend it as its supported by google and abstracts some of the complexities in the signed url dance

First get a certificate
https://console.developers.google.com/

Save the certificate to your project

Install google cloud library

```
pip install google-cloud-storage==1.9.0
```

Import generate_signed_url and google.storage and then initialize storage client with the certificate and access the bucket

```
from google.cloud.storage._signing import generate_signed_url
from google.cloud import storage

client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('path/to/certificate.json')

expiration = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
API_ACCESS_ENDPOINT = 'https://storage.googleapis.com'
canonical_resource = bucketpath + "resource.jpeg"

url = generate_signed_url(
    client._credentials, resource=canonical_resource,
    api_access_endpoint=API_ACCESS_ENDPOINT,
    expiration=expiration, method="PUT",
    content_type="jpeg"
)
print(url)
```

full documentation
https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/client.html

Comment: You are the best! Thanks for ending my struggle to find this solution!

Comment: The problem with the approach is that CORS headers aren't included in response no matter what bucket's cors options are. Looking for the solution either the way to sign simple POST url or xml/json url